# Passing params to the controller rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a few links:

```
<%= link_to "", '../captures#photos' %>
<%= link_to "", '../captures#videos' %>
<%= link_to "", '../captures#audios' %>
```

They pass to the captures_controller.rb

How do I parse the paramaters (photos / videos / audios) from not going to index in the controller?

Currently in the controller I have:

```
def photos
  logger.debug 'photos'
end
def videos
  logger.debug 'videos'
end
def audios
  logger.debug 'audios'
end

def index
  logger.debug 'index'
end
```

But all of the following urls log "index"?

- .../captures
- .../captures#photos
- .../captures#videos
- .../captures#audios

routes.rb:

```
# these were when I was trying the links without the hashes
match 'captures/photos' => 'captures#photos'
match 'captures/videos' => 'captures#videos'
match 'captures/audios' => 'captures#audios'

resources :captures
resources :photos
resources :audios
resources :videos
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have in your routes.rb file? You should probably be using the route helpers rather than trying to define the urls yourself. By the way all of those urls will just route to the index page - the # refers to a named anchor in a url, not a controller action (as it does in routes.rb).

Answer (score 1):

In rails 4.0 you can attach and pass the attributes through the GET request in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

This will heavily depend on your routes defined in the `routes.rb` file, but regardless you can't use the hash portion (Anything that comes after the `#`) as part of your routes. In fact browsers won't even send it along to the server anyway. Most likely you want your URLs to look like:

```
../captures
../captures/photos
../captures/videos
../captures/audios
```

Typically it's best to not specify your URLs in your `link_to` functions like this either. You want to use your routing helper functions to provide them in case your routes ever change.

I'd suggest reading the [Ruby on Rails Guide to Routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). That will provide a lot of insight into how to use the functions built into Rails to get the most out of your routes.

Comment: Now that you've posted your routes file, using the URLs I mentioned above will work. When you see it say `match 'captures/photos' => 'captures#photos'` in the routes, it is saying map the `captures/photos` URL to the `captures` controller's `photos` action. The `#` is there to separate the controller and action definition.

Comment: So, how should the link_to look?   It wants to access the #show action.   I commented out the show action, but the local variable action is "#show", so I understand that to mean that it is being passed the action #show from somewhere.    I have tried manually setting the action in the link_to looking like: `link_to "", photos_captures_path, :action => :photos`, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: To create a `link_to` to a specific controller and action you can use: `link_to 'Photos', :controller => "captures", :action => "photos"`. That will work for your `match` lines in the routes file. I'd suggest reading the guide I posted, as I'm not positive you're using the `resources` route correctly. Each one of those is going to map to a different controller.

Comment: yeah,    ive read,   it makes only partial sense.   So I am trying a few projects I am familiar with to help me acclimate.   Trying so hard to be a programmer....

Answer (score 0):

In **routes.rb**:

```
get "/captures/:format"
```

And in whichever **captures_controller.rb** methods you need it in:

```
@format = params[:format]
```

Then anywhere in your relevant view `@format` will output either `photos`, `videos`, or `audios`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use the `controller#action` notation in `link_to`. You have to either give it a path, like `/captures/photos` or specify some arguments explicitly. Try this:

```
<%= link_to "", :controller => "captures", :action => "photos" %>
```

I'd also do this in routes.rb to simplify things:

```
resources :captures
  get :photos
  get :photo_booths
  get :videos
  get :audios
end
```

which will let you do this:

```
<%= link_to "", photos_captures_path %>
```

Finally, based purely on the limited code you've shown us, it actually sounds like you should have *resources* named `photos`, `audios`, etc, each with their own controllers, by using "captures" as namespace and making separate controllers for each type:

```
namespace :captures do
  resources :photos
  resources :photo_booths
  #etc
end
```

Then each one has an `index` action that serves the current function of each method in your controller. Then your links just look like:

```
<%= link_to "", captures_photos_path %>
```